# Polymer IronResizableBehavior iron-resize event not fired when "resizable" element is hidden/un-hidden as described in docs

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

Below is the Polymer IronResizableBehavior demo modified to fire based on the "resizable" element being hidden or un-hidden rather than just on the window being resized.  The event is fired when the window is resized, but the Polymer docs (https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-resizable-behavior) indicate:

> This event will be fired when they become showing after having been hidden, when they are resized explicitly by another resizable, or when the window has been resized.

So, I would expect the event to also be fired when I hide/un-hide the "x-puck" element below.  What am I doing wrong?

```
<link rel="import" href="../../iron-resizable-behavior.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../../paper-button/paper-button.html">

<dom-module id="x-puck">
  <style>
  </style>

  <template>

    <b>I'm an un-hidden element!</b>

  </template>

</dom-module>

<script>
  Polymer({

    is: 'x-puck',

    behaviors: [
      Polymer.IronResizableBehavior
    ],

    listeners: {
      'iron-resize': '_onIronResize'
    },

    attached: function() {
      this.async(this.notifyResize, 1);
    },

    _onIronResize: function() {
      alert('x-puck _onIronResize called!');
    }
  });
</script>


<dom-module id="x-app">
  <style>
  </style>

  <template>
    <paper-button on-tap="showElement">Show</paper-button>
    <paper-button on-tap="hideElement">Hide</paper-button>

    <x-puck id="xPuck" hidden$="{{hide}}"></x-puck>
  </template>

</dom-module>

<script>
  Polymer({

    is: 'x-app',

    behaviors: [
      Polymer.IronResizableBehavior
    ],

    properties: {
      hide: {
        type: Boolean,
        value: true
      }
    },

    showElement: function() {
      this.hide = false;
    },

    hideElement: function() {
      this.hide = true;
    }
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked fastly at the source code of `IronResizableBehavior` and didn't see anything that would support that an element implementing it will be resized whenever its CCS `display` property is changed (it's essentially what the `hidden` attribute does).

Looking at the `iron-pages` element, [you can see that it explicitely calls `notifyResize` whenever an element is unhidden](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-pages/blob/master/iron-pages.html#L83), so I supposed this is the way it works.

I would suggest you to open [an issue on the Github repo](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-pages/issues) in order to get more feedback on this, and to correct this misleading statement if I'm right.

Comment: Your analysis is correct. It's not easy to tell if an element has been hidden in the general sense (or resized for that matter) so the entire rasion d'etre for the IronResizableBehavior is to have a way to notify subtrees explicitly when changes are made.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: IMO, you are also correct that the documentation is misleading. https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-resizable-behavior/issues/16